# How to create a slider with json responds

Tags: javascript

Json Data

```
{"code":1,
 "msg":"OK",
 "details":{"gallery_photo": ["https:\/\/www.yourdomain.in\/upload\/tet.jpg","https:\/\/www.yourdomain.in\/upload\/tet.jpg","https:\/\/www.yourdomain.in\/upload\/tet.jpg"]}}
```

I am storing the data in Case mode

```
case "getItemDetails":

                displayItemGall(data.details);

            break;
```

And the function i created, can not create a loop

```
    function displayItemGall(data)
{       
var gallery = JSON.parse(data).gallery_photo;
        var html_gallery='';
                $.each(gallery, function( key, val ) {
                        html_gallery+='<a>';
                        html_gallery+='<img src="'+val+'" data-src="'+val+'" class="preload-image responsive-image" alt="img">';
                        html_gallery+='</a>';

                   });

                   createElement("item-info2",html_gallery);
}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(data).gallery_photo;` You don't need to parse it. As you are passing your object then just write: `data.gallery_photo;`

Comment: but it can't show

Comment: exact error....? can you show or add in your post?

Comment: same error .. it can't create a loop images

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: [check it out](https://jsfiddle.net/o4rqye9g)